# FAILED: dbconnection com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure while executing SQL query through Selenium

Tags: sql-server, selenium, selenium-webdriver, database-connection, database-testing

I have made the sql connection , and fetching the query from excel sheet. 
and after establishing db cooncetion, calling:

```
result rs= st.executeQuery(query)
```

statement is showing error as couldnot find storedprocedure.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String querypath = "C:/Users/svhirekalmath/eclipse-workspace/NepalBITestNg/queries/queries.xlsx"; 
FileInputStream queryFile = new FileInputStream(new File(querypath));
XSSFWorkbook queryBook = new XSSFWorkbook(queryFile);
Sheet querySheet=queryBook.getSheet("Sheet1");

String query=ReusableFunctions.getPropertiesValue("COMPANY"); // fetching query 
queryBook.close(); 

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://cdtssql879d;database=NepalBI_1","SNABI_user","SNABI@123");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query); // getting error at this line
```

Error:

```
FAILED: dbconnection
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'applicationPassword'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:786)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:685)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:620)
    at marketoverview.MarketOverviewTest.dbconnection(MarketOverviewTest.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Please help me on this, as i am new on learning automation .

Comment: Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query); // getting error in this line

Comment: Removed Selenium related tags since this question has nothing to do with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
FAILED: dbconnection
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'applicationPassword'.
```

...implies that there was an error while your program tried to execute the **query**.

A bit more details about the line:

```
String query=ReusableFunctions.getPropertiesValue("COMPANY");
```

would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However, the standard structure of a pl/sql statement to be executed through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is as follows:

```
String query = "select * from seleniumuser"
```

So ideally,

```
String query=ReusableFunctions.getPropertiesValue("COMPANY");
System.out.println(query);
```

should print something similar to:

```
select * from seleniumuser
```

Additionally, the instance of the `Connection` should have included the port number as follows:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/selenium","root","root");
```

The port number seems to be missing from your code trial:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://cdtssql879d;database=NepalBI_1","SNABI_user","SNABI@123");
```

> **Note**: @JimEvans in his comment further clarified that *Selenium has any support for executing SQL queries is misleading. It’s standard Java library execution, and has absolutely nothing to do with Selenium*

Comment: I’m normally fine with your answers about Selenium, but implying as you do that Selenium has any support for executing SQL queries is misleading. It’s standard Java library execution, and has absolutely nothing to do with Selenium. This answer should reflect that.

Comment: @JimEvans I am not sure where within the answer I would have incorporated your valuable comments so I added your comment as a **Note** at the end.

Comment: @DebanjanB `the standard structure of a pl/sql statement to be executed through Selenium is as follows:` is where he saw it.

Comment: The implication is in this sentence: “However, the standard structure of a pl/sql statement to be executed through Selenium is as follows:” That should be worded differently.